# How to apply filter on remote data

Tags: angular, kendo-treeview

I am stuck on an issue on kendo-treeview angular. In static data filter is working but on remote data filter is not working.

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/treeview/data-binding/#toc-remote-heterogeneous-data

Answer (score 0):

The remote data filter is not going to work out of the box. You have to implement it manually. See https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/treeview/filtering/#toc-manual-filtering for details.
To do that:

1. Add [filterable]="true"
2. Listen for (filterChange) event
3. Filter categories

See my proof of concept based on kendo example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moowpy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Filtering children or filtering categories based on children's data is possible but more complicated because it requires changing the API. I can imagine some additional request that would return categories based on filter query. But that depends on your application logic and architectural decisions.

Comment: I have already implemented these functionality. But in this functionality we have able to search parent node not able to child node.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer to search across child nodes you have to implement an additional API that returns categories by a search query. Otherwise, it's not going to work.